# How to find text in a Lua script

Tags: search, lua, minecraft, computercraft

I'm trying to code some kind of search engine in Minecraft ComputerCraft and haven't found any kind of code to look for text in a page.

I've already tried to use the string.find() and string.match() command but they only looked for text in one certain string. I'm looking for script that looks for text in the whole script.

You see what I've tried in the image below
[image]

Comment: Sounds like your issue is actually that you're only getting the first occurrence of the string you're looking for.

Instead of match you could use gmatch if this is the case.

Comment: any reason why you need to code in-game?

Comment: You have two problems: 1. you haven't read the description of what `string.find` does and 2. the function you want doesn't exist. Lua itself doesn't know how to deal with files and the computercraft API doesn't really have a "search in all files" function either. In other words, you will actually have to write this yourself.